# Are in-dialog intents supported in the ActionsSdkApp

Tags: actions-on-google

Are in-dialog intents supported? I tried something that I thought might work. It didn't. I'm wondering if I need to look harder for a bug on my part or if I can't get there from here. I looked at the ask() method:

```
    ask (inputPrompt, dialogState) {
    debug('ask: inputPrompt=%s, dialogState=%s',
       JSON.stringify(inputPrompt), JSON.stringify(dialogState));
    const expectedIntent = this.buildExpectedIntent_(this.StandardIntents.TEXT, []);
    if (!expectedIntent) {
      error('Error in building expected intent');
      return null;
    }
    return this.buildAskHelper_(inputPrompt, [expectedIntent], dialogState);
  }
```

It is specifying the name of the intent where the user's response will end up. The comments above the buildExpectedIntent_() method have this quip

```
intent Developer specified in-dialog intent inside the Action
   *     Package or an App built-in intent like
   *     'assistant.intent.action.TEXT'.
```

So I thought I might be able to create a new method by starting with the ask method and adding a parameter to take the name of an in-dialog intent and then defining the intent in my action package. I don't see an obvious error when I do that but my text intent is the one that gets the text spoken by the user, not the in-dialog intent.

Should this work - that is should I keep looking for where I went wrong?

While I'm at it, there is also this

```
 * Refer to {@link ActionsSdkApp#newRuntimeEntity} to create
 * the list of runtime entities required by this method.
 * Runtime entities need to be defined in the Action Package.
```

just above the description of the intent. What are runtime entities in this context?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to match any user defined intent using the Actions SDK integration after the **MAIN** intent as all the next intents will match the **TEXT** intent unless it's a built-in intent (system intent). You can find more info on **ExpectedIntent** in [this page](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#ExpectedIntent).
User defined intents are only accessible through deep-linking. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/define-actions).

Comment: Thanks @Nazeem. Your explanation is inline with everything I've heard over the last 8 months. And I've got a half dozen or so deep links in my Action but the way I understand the term they aren't "in-dialog". Further, "in-dialog" intents are a thing. See this https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/app-exits. The issue is though that our understanding it is at odds with the comment. It would be nice if someone close to the code could remove the comment if it's bogus or explain how to make this work.

Comment: @WilliamDePalo I'm aware that in-dialog intents exist but they only can be built-in intents. In the example you gave the intent is "actions.intent.CANCEL"

Comment: I know what you are saying. It is at odds with comments in the source code. I'd be fine if the comment was removed. Call me old-fashioned (which I am) but it is a good thing when the comments don't lead you astray.